# unresolved reference android in android studio, kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g37MW.png)

I want to import the xml file activity_settings and it says unreloved reference android, ive never seen this and i have no idea what todo.

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved it by adding:
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
to the gradle file!